# Как вывести те слова из файла, последняя буква которых равна первой букве следующего через stream

Tags: java, алгоритм, потоки-данных, java-stream

У меня есть файл. Его содержимое

```
Hello World!
Hello Java!
Apple Eagle Apple
Dog Ground Dog
```

Я написал метод

```
public static List<String> getWordsListEndingWithLetterEqualFirstLetterOfNextWord(String file) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")));
        }
        return list.stream()
                .filter((i -> i.charAt(i.length() - 1) == (i + 1).charAt(0)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Сначала я разбиваю файл по отдельным словам, а потом добавляю в список. Далее через stream я пытаюсь сравнить последнюю букву элемента с первой буквой следующего элемента. Вот только не понимаю почему вместо `==` я не могу использовать `equalsIsIgnoreCase()`. Могу только в случае, если убрать `charAt()`. Даже если заменить все заглавные буквы на строчные, то выведет только `eagle`(видимо, переход на след. элемент я неправильно прописал и сравниваются 1-ая и последняя буква слова). Очень приветствуется объяснение того, почему это не работает.

Ожидаемый вывод

```
[Apple, Dog, Ground]
```

Comment: а где здесь вообще сравнение предыдущего и следующего элементов?

Comment: @Дмитрий `.filter((i -> i.charAt(i.length() - 1) == (i + 1).charAt(0)))` Думал, i + 1 сработает. Не понимаю как в стриме указать переход на след элемент.

Comment: в переменную i вы поочередно получаете все элементы вашей коллекции. таким образом для Apple при выполнении (i + 1) вы прибавляете к  Apple единицу и получаете Apple1. такой подход со стримом не работает, это же не цикл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробуйте так:

```
public static List<String> getWordsListEndingWithLetterEqualFirstLetterOfNextWord(String file) throws IOException {
    
    final List<String> list = Files.lines(Paths.get(file))
            .flatMap(line->Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size()-1)
            .filter(i -> {
                String current = list.get(i);
                String next = list.get(i+1);
                return current.substring(current.length()-1).equalsIgnoreCase(next.substring(0, 1));
            })
            .mapToObj(list::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: `.mapToObj(list::get)` передает в список текущий элемент, верно ? Мне нужен предыдущий элемент, последняя буква которого совпала с первой буквой текущего. Так же у меня вопрос исходя из вашего комментария о том, что такой подход не работает. Стоит ли вообще тогда так заморачиваться со стримом в этой задаче или просто переделать под for ? Так же мне понравился ваш способ заполнить список при объявлении. Очень удобно. Возьму на заметку.

Comment: @Tokamo ответ я исправил, хотя особых отличий нет. стоит ли заморачиваться - решать вам.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо за помощь